# How to populate the store and sequentially await return using Redux Observable?

Tags: redux-observable

I am attempting to use Redux Observable to call an action to fetch some data, wait for its return, then fetch some more data that relies on it.

I have an epic which populates a store from a fetch `FetchTodos`.  This listens for the `FETCH_TODOS` action and then calls my todos API and populates `{todos: [] } =`

I also have a comments section in my store `todoComments`.  However, I would like to only populate `todoComments` once `FETCH_TODOS` has returned and populated the store.

In imperative code, this might look like:

```
let todos = await api.get('/todos');
await dispatch("FETCH_TODO_COMPLETE", todos)
let firstId = getState().todos[0].id
let comments = await api.get(`/todos/${firstId}/comments')
await dispatch("FETCH_COMMENTS_COMPLETE", { todo_id: firstId, comments})
```

The closest I saw to this was [this issue](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/33) in the Redux Observable Repo, but I could not understand how to do this efficiently.  This is a pretty common scenario for me.

I would like to reuse as much code as possible.  In this example, I may dispatch `FETCH_TODOS` from multiple components.

How would i accomplish this with Redux-Observable?

Comment: In your example you only fetch the comments for the first todo in the list `let firstId = getState().todos[0].id` is that exactly what you want to do, or are you wanting to fetch the comments of a specific todo by ID, or the comments for all the todos?

Comment: It's more just to show that comments would have to wait on the todos.   The sequencing of fetches and accessing the state in between is the key part.

Comment: It changes how you would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our conversation in the comments:

In redux-observable, you can sequence things in numerous ways. You could do it all in one epic using normal RxJS, or you could split them into multiple ones. If you split them, the subsequent epic would listen for the signal that the previous one has completed its task. Something like this:

```
// this assumes you make your `api.get` helper return an Observable
// instead of a Promise which is highly advisable.
// If it doesn't, you could do:
//   Observable.from(api.get('/url'))
// but Promises are not truly cancellable which can cause max
// concurrent connections issues

const fetchTodosEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('FETCH_TODOS')
    .switchMap(() =>
      api.get('/todos')
        .map(todos => ({
          type: 'FETCH_TODOS_COMPLETE',
          todos
        }))
    );

const fetchComments = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('FETCH_TODOS_COMPLETE')
    .switchMap(({ todos }) =>
      api.get(`/todos/${todos[0].id}/comments`)
        .map(comments => ({
          type: 'FETCH_COMMENTS_COMPLETE',
          comments
        }))
    );
```

Comment: With these 2 epics, how would I combine them into one epic call?  Imagine I landed on a comment page, and only had the Id of the comment, and had to fetch all the todos and all the comments to render the component.  Ie., there was an action called FETCH_COMMENT that passed a comment id, but I had to fetch all the todos, then all the comments into my redux store to look up that comment.

Comment: If you have the comment ID, why do you need to wait for anything else?

Comment: @jayphelps What about if you want to chain 2 actions (first one calls 4 different queries and the other one triggers a reducer if all 4 queries succeed). Would it be possible using redux-observable?

Comment: @jayphelps if you want to give the caller of the epic control over the next action (e.g. onSuccess or onFailure), is it a good idea to give an epic an action that contains another action?  For example, an ajax epic could be given an action which includes an "onSuccess" action that can be returned by the epic if the ajax call is successful.

Comment: @mikebridge as long as the actions are serializable it's prolly fine, though I personally wouldn't do it. If the goal is to reduce boilerplate, I would use factories to make unique epics for each use case, e.g. `createWhateverEpic({ onSuccess: whateverActionCreator, ...etc })`. If you ask a new SO question I'm happy to take a look. I watch the redux-observable tag

Comment: @jayphelps Thanks---I was thinking in terms of chaining actions with promises, which doesn't seem like the right mental model with redux-observable.  I think I can simplify this by rewriting it as a series of reactions to redux state changes.  (Although an epic factory sounds like an interesting concept.)

Comment: @jayphelps coming back to this issue, if I want to perform something "promise"-like, would it be unwise to [dynamically create an epic](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/AddingNewEpicsAsynchronously.html) which listens for one event only and then unsubscribes itself?